# Redirect to a *specific* Lightning Record Page

Tags: lightning

I have a number of Lightning Record Pages on the `Account` object, is it possible via apex/javascript/any other means to redirect to different record pages based on some specified criteria?

Google hasn't turned up anything so I suspect not, but wanted to check if anyone had managed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** redirect a User to any other Lightning Record Page, if the User does not have access to that particular page. A User in Lightning Experience gets to see only those Lightning Record Pages, which are assigned to them while activating the page.

When you create a Lighting Record Page, you need to [activate the page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages_activate.htm&type=5) to be available to the Users, and that while activating any page, you only have *two* options.

> You have **two** activation options. You can make your custom record page the default record page for all users, assign it to specific Lightning apps, or assign it to record types and profiles. Assigning the page to a Lightning app, record type, or profile gives your users access to a record page customized for the context they’re working in.